# Audio output of Alexapi on raspberry pi only works with hdmi and not with speakers through the 3.5 mm audio jack

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-4, alexa

Alexa speaks and listens to my voice when I run the Sample App. However, I can only hear Alexa from an hdmi TV and not from a speaker even after trying the following steps. Even though the audio output for Youtube videos comes from the aux (speaker) on my pi, Alexa works only with the hdmi output.

1. Forcing audio output to audio jack from raspi-config
2. Running a headless setup and commenting hdmi_force_hotplug=1.
3. changing the file in /home/pi/avs-device-sdk/MediaPlayer/GStreamerMediaPlayer/src m_pipeline.audioSink = gst_element_factory_make("audioSinkElement.c_str()", "audio_sink"); to
   m_pipeline.audioSink = gst_element_factory_make("alsasink", "audio_sink"); after reading up about it in github.
   Is there ant fix for this that I am missing?